# Post string and access via $_POST on PHP using Flurl?

Tags: c#, xamarin, flurl

Is it possible to send a `HTTP POST` with `Flurl` or `Flurl.Http` so I can access it server-side like `$_POST['foo']`?

I was able to post json before like

```
dynamic responses = await Serverpath.PostJsonAsync(
                       new { foo = "foo", bar = "bar" })
                       .ReceiveJsonList();
```

and received it server sided

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

But now I just want to send a little string and access it via the $_POST variable, so it that possible if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

That was easier than I thought.

I came up with this solution

```
dynamic response = await ServerAddress.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { foo = "bar" });
```

Serverside: `$_POST['foo']`

Comment: You beat me to it. :) I'm not a PHP guy but guessing $_POST is typically for inspecting data posted from HTML forms, which are sent sent URL-encoded, so you're spot on.

Comment: @ToddMenier sometimes i'm faster in writing than in using my brain :) However, Flurl is yours right? Guess i got a bug in `ReceiveJsonList();` on Android and WinPhone it works just fine However on iOS I get an Exception `Request to [...] failed´ even if the `Flurl.Http.HttpCall` gives me . But if i replace `ReceiveJsonList()` with `ReceiveString()` I get the reponse on iOS (but not in the format I want) any reason for that and a fix available?